# C & Mac: trouble finding a header using pkg-config

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to use  in one of my projects. I'm working on a Mac, have gotten MacPorts with pkg-config and glib-2.0 packages.

When I try to make a file containing an include to above path, I get the following error (line above it is for clarity that it does actually give me the right dirs):

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl 
$ make
gcc hash-glib.c -c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
hash-glib.c:2:23: error: glib/glib.h: No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: Please reduce your shell prompt to a single character (`$`, `#` and `%` are traditional for normal user, root, and C-shell users respectively).  It makes it easier to see the commands.

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up, never knew.

Comment: Does any of the directories listed have a `glib/glib.h` file, or just a `glib.h` file directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you've run:

```
ls -l /opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include/glib/glib.h \
      /opt/local/include/glib/glib.h
```

to demonstrate that the header `#include "glib/glib.h"` actually is present in one of the locations where you've been told by `pkg-config` that it could be found.  If it isn't there, then `pkg-config` is misleading you, and the compiler is telling you that you've been hoodwinked.

Since the compiler will have done its utmost to find the header, it is a reasonable bet that the file isn't in either of those locations.  You are then left with detective work: where is the `glib.h` header installed?

```
find /opt/local -type f -name glib.h
```

If that tells you where it is, you can then work out what `pkg-config` should be saying.  If that fails to find it, widen the search area.  If you still can't find it, maybe it isn't installed yet?  Or you only installed the glib runtime, not the development package.

Comment: My bad. I was looking in the wrong direction entirely: there was a flipping typo in my code. Thanks alot for making me check the file paths again.